# How to inherit a RuntimeException class?

Tags: java, design-patterns, exception

I have two options:

```
public class SyntaxException extends RuntimeException {
  private String msg;
  public SyntaxException(String m) {
    this.msg = m;
  }
  public String getMessage() {
    return "Invalid syntax: " + this.msg;
  }
}
```

and

```
public class SyntaxException extends RuntimeException {
  public SyntaxException(String m) {
    super("Invalid syntax: " + m);
  }
}
```

Which one is preferred, if I have to think about code maintainability and extendability?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Use the second one. The argument to the constructor of both `RuntimeException` and your inherited class is the error message, so there's no reason to duplicate that functionality already given by `RuntimeException` in your code.

Answer (score 2):

Im going with number 2. Number one looks like reinventing the wheel.

Also, thinking about [YAGNI](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/You_ain%27t_gonna_need_it) and [KISS](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/KISS_principle), it seems that the `getMessage()` method and the `msg` attribute will bring no additional value to your class. Moreover, if someone else runs into it while reading your code, i'm guessing he/she will say or think "why is he/she redefining these things".

If in the future you need a custom `getMessage()` method, write it then.

Answer (score 1):

Not the first one.

If "Invalid syntax: " is part of your message, the you can use this:

```
public class SyntaxException extends RuntimeException {
  public SyntaxException(String wrongSyntax) {
    super("Invalid syntax: " + wrongSyntax);
  }
}
```

But at least it depends on the fact: whether you need i18n or not.

Answer (score 0):

The second.  Since the base class already has a message, it makes sense to use it.